# Create List only if Session doesn't exist

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

### The goal

Create a List only if Session doesn't exist.

### The problem

Visual Studio returns me:

> The name `products` doesn't exist in the current context.

I have the following code:

```
public ActionResult Add(int productId)
{
    if (Session["ShoppingList"] == null)
    {
        List<int> products = new List<int>();
    }

    products.Add(productId);
    Session["ShoppingList"] = products;
    return View("Index");
}
```

Yes, I know, I did not set out the `if` the `products` variable. But, if the Session exists, means that the "List" already exists and theoretically the `products` already exists too.

So, how can I "fix" this?

Comment: Define `products` outside of your if statement; actually, if I read your question correctly, you should pull products from session if it exists, or create the new list if it's not in session.

Comment: @Tim Hm.. Like what?...

Comment: Your theory is incorrect.  That's a local variable, it exists _only_ within that scope.

Comment: @chiefGui If you declare a variable inside of an if or a try it will not be considered to exist outside the if or try because there is a possibility that it might not exist. You need to guarantee the existence of some space in order to use it in other scopes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

More concise code that doesn't require you to reassign `Session["ShoppingList"]` each time:

```
public ActionResult Add(int productId)
{
    if (Session["ShoppingList"] == null)
    {
        Session["ShoppingList"] = new List<int>();
    }

    ((List<int>)Session["ShoppingList"]).Add(productId);
    return View("Index");
}
```

Comment: @chiefGui FYI - Jay's answer about encapsulating the session access is a very good idea. In fact, it's a good idea for anything that uses string literals as keys, like ViewState or the asp.net profile provider.

Answer (score 4):

Try defining the variable `products` outside the `if`, if session variable is null you create a new list, otherwise you retrieve the one stored in the session variable:

```
public ActionResult Add(int productId)
{
    List<int> products;

    if (Session["ShoppingList"] == null)
    {
        products = new List<int>();
    }
    else
    {
        products = (List<int>) Session["ShoppingList"];
    }

    products.Add(productId);
    Session["ShoppingList"] = products;
    return View("Index");
}
```

Comment: Error List returns me: `'object' does not contain a definition for 'Add' and no extension method 'Add' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)` and: `Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<int>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)`

Comment: You need to cast Session["ShoppingList"] to List<int>

Answer (score 4):

I'm not 100% positive If I get the question, but this may do the trick

```
public ActionResult Add(int productId)
{
    var products = Session["ShoppingList"] as List<int> ?? new List<int>();
    products.Add(productId);
    Session["ShoppingList"] = products;
    return View("Index");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

What you have here is something called Variable Scope. Because the variable `products` is defined in a child block it will not be visible outside that block.

Perhaps this is what you were going for?

```
public ActionResult Add(int productId)
{

    if (Session["ShoppingList"] == null)
    {           
        Session["ShoppingList"] = new List<int>();
    }

    List<int> products = (List<int>)Session["ShoppingList"]
    products.Add(productId);
    return View("Index");

}
```

Truely access to session should be encapsulated like so:

```
public static class SessionStore
{
    private const string shoppingListKey = "ShoppingList";
    public static List<int> ShoppingList
    {
        get
        {
            return Session[shoppingListKey] ??                      
               (Session[shoppingListKey] = new List<int>());
        }
    }
}
```

now in your controller you can just

```
SessionStore.ShoppingList.Add(productId)
```

and not worry about it.

Comment: SessionStore class must to be within which folder?

Comment: In an MVC application it (most) doesn't matter, but for sanity I would suggest creating a /Components folder or putting it in /Models. Good question.

Comment: Oh, thanks. But it seems that the Session is not set and I'm using the `System.Web` namespace on `/Components/SessionStore.cs/`

Comment: Session is actually mapped to a property `Session` on the controller. In the static class you can access it via `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session` Lengthy, but its there.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler is complaining because products is declared inside the if code block, which has its own scope. After the code block, products is out of scope, and can't be referenced. The two easiest ways to fix this are either declare product before entering into the scope of the if block, and only instantiate it inside the block, or to declare and instantiate it, plus assign it to `Session["ShoppingList"]` inside the if block.

Answer (score 1):

```
public ActionResult Add(int productId)
{
    if (Session["ShoppingList"] == null)
    {
        List<int> products = new List<int>(); //#1 conditionally creates the variable only if it is null
    }

    products.Add(productId);
    Session["ShoppingList"] = products; //#2 makes the session equal to something that may not ever actually exist
    return View("Index");
}
```

Your problem lies in number #2 what if the products variable is never created? Would you like the compiler to put a blank string? Would you like it to put null? Would you like it to put a 0? What does products even refer to if #1 is never executed? You need to take the first part of #1 and move it out of your if statement and simply assign a value to products in the if statement without the List before products.